# How does Google Analytics get its data i.e. User gender?

Tags: google-analytics

I was wondering how Google Analytics found out so much user information? I understand some of the details, but how does it determine the gender of the user, or age?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use cookies!

For an overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

From Google: How Google determines demographic information

When someone visits a website that has partnered with the Google Display Network, Google stores a number in their browsers (using a "cookie") to remember their visits. This number uniquely identifies a web browser on a specific computer, not a specific person. Browsers may be associated with a demographic category, such as gender or age range, based on the sites that were visited.

In addition, some sites might provide us with demographic information that people share on certain websites, such as social networking sites. We may also use demographics derived from Google profiles.

================================

So basically Google collects third party information and uses a cookie to track browsing habits that they send to Google Analytics.

You can read more here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2580383

Comment: Thank you! That answered all of my questions!!

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation and external references :)